# Is there any way to connect a docker container to local IP address?

Tags: docker

I'm running docker daemon from my virtual box and when i start a container it runs on `docker0` interface with `172.XX.XX.XXX` ip address but I would like to attach the container to physical IP address i.e `10.XX.XX.XXX`.

Can you please let me know the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make virtual hosts routed back to your own machine.

Update the **hosts** file. under `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\`(window) or `/etc/hosts` (linux)

e.g.

```
10.XX.XX.XXX    172.XX.XX.XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a virtual-box host to guest problem i suppose.

After publish container's port, host can access container by request guest ip.

You can set a [host-only network interface](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) for guest or set a [bridged interface](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged)